# how to control slider with play/pause button in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a 360 view written in actionscript 3. How do I control the slider with the play/pause button? I'm able to get the code to work but I just can't figure out a way to control the slider with the play/pause button. I'm using this for a product viewer.

```
    private function createSlider():void
    {
        //Create a librarie object in the stage.
        _roteableObject = new LibrarieObject();
        _roteableObject.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _roteableObject.width / 2;
        _roteableObject.y = 0;
        _roteableObject.gotoAndStop(1);
        addChild(_roteableObject);

        //Create the slider
        _slider = new Slider();
        _slider.minimum = 1;
        _slider.maximum = _roteableObject.totalFrames;
        addChild(_slider);
        _slider.width = stage.stageWidth - 250;
        _slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderChangeHandler);
        _slider.move(stage.stageWidth / 2 - _slider.width / 2 + 90, _roteableObject.y + 25 + _roteableObject.height - 10);
        _slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stop360);


        //play / stop button
        _play_btn = new play_btn();
        _stop_btn = new stop_btn();
             addChild(_play_btn);
        addChild(_stop_btn);
        _stop_btn.visible = false;
        _play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play360);
        _stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop360);
    }

    private function sliderChangeHandler(e:Event):void 
    {
        _roteableObject.gotoAndStop(e.target.value);
    }

    private function play360(e:Event):void
    {
        _roteableObject.play();
        _play_btn.visible = false;
        _stop_btn.visible = true;
    }
    private function stop360(e:Event):void
    {
        _roteableObject.stop();
        _play_btn.visible = true;
        _stop_btn.visible = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification that should do what you're looking for. It adds an `ENTER_FRAME` listener to the `roteableObject` variable when you click to play. On each new frame it sets the slider's `value` property to the current frame number of `roteableObject`, and the listener is removed when `stop360()` is called.

```
    private function createSlider():void
    {
        //Create a librarie object in the stage.
        _roteableObject = new LibrarieObject();
        _roteableObject.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _roteableObject.width / 2;
        _roteableObject.y = 0;
        _roteableObject.gotoAndStop(1);
        addChild(_roteableObject);

        //Create the slider
        _slider = new Slider();
        _slider.minimum = 1;
        _slider.maximum = _roteableObject.totalFrames;
        addChild(_slider);
        _slider.width = stage.stageWidth - 250;
        _slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderChangeHandler);
        _slider.move(stage.stageWidth / 2 - _slider.width / 2 + 90, _roteableObject.y + 25 + _roteableObject.height - 10);
        _slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stop360);


        //play / stop button
        _play_btn = new play_btn();
        _stop_btn = new stop_btn();
        addChild(_play_btn);
        addChild(_stop_btn);
        _stop_btn.visible = false;
        _play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play360);
        _stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop360);
    }

    private function sliderChangeHandler(e:Event):void 
    {
        _roteableObject.gotoAndStop(e.target.value);
    }

    private function play360(e:Event):void
    {
        //Listen to new frame events
        _roteableObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, roteableObject_enterFrame);

        _roteableObject.play();
        _play_btn.visible = false;
        _stop_btn.visible = true;
    }

    private function stop360(e:Event):void
    {
        //Stop listening to new frame events
        if (_roteableObject.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) _roteableObject.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, roteableObject_enterFrame);

        _roteableObject.stop();
        _play_btn.visible = true;
        _stop_btn.visible = false;
    }

    private function roteableObject_enterFrame(evt:Event):void
    {
        //Update slider position with current frame
        _slider.value = _roteableObject.currentFrame;
    }
```